# How to download and read a .txt file from http URL using my servlet

Tags: java, servlets, text, download

I'm a young and new developer, and I never worked with Java servlets. 
I have a http URL that allows me to download a .txt file (For example : http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt)

So I built a Java servlet inspired by what I've seen on other posts. My goal is to download and read this .txt file.
I would like to put this downloaded file in my "data.txt".

The ServletDownload class :

```
public class ServletDownload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final int BYTES_DOWNLOAD = 1024;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename=downloadname.txt");
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("Donnees/data.txt");

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Now I don't know if my code is well done and **how to use it with my URL** ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The end of your code could be something like that (with the try-with-resources statement to properly close the streams):

```
try (InputStream is = new URL("http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt").openStream();
     OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];

    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks !
Another question, now I have this servlet, how can i call the doGet method in another class ? 
Precisely, how can I initialize "request" and "response" in another class ?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: If you need to be able to do the same thing elsewhere consider extracting the part of the code that you want to reuse in an utility class for example and call the related utility method from the different classes.

Comment: I'm working on an existing app, this app read a .txt file and generate PDF files. Before, the .txt files were on a folder. Now they are downloadable with an http URL, and I MUST une a servlet.
So I add to the existing project a new class (the servlet) to download the .txt files and I don't really know how to une it.
I never use a servlet before...

Comment: this is a different question, If you never use any Servlet before, you should read doc about it and/or do the tutorials like this one for example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/